# Regular Expression Replace on Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need a regular expression to replace the value in XML tags. I need to find * and replace it with XXXXX. I made an attempt to do this but its giving me "invalid regex".

```
<TAG>\('(.*?'\)</TAG>
// replace with:
<TAG>XXXXX</TAG>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your actual starting content is something like this:

```
<TAG>some content here</TAG>
```

If you want to mask the content of such tags, you may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    <TAG>(.*?)</TAG>
Replace: <TAG>XXXXX</TAG>
```

### Demo

Note that in general it is not desirable to manipulate nested content like XML/HTML using regex.  But sometimes, e.g. when using tools like NPP, we are forced to do this.  My answer should work fine assuming you are only targeting `<TAG>` elements which have no other children tags inside of them.

Comment: Tim, you are a life saver. Thank you so much.